# Visual Studio 2022, unable to view code in form

Tags: vb.net

Have not used VS for a number of years and a bit rusty....

In a Visual Basic windows form designer, I add a button, double click it and this normally brings up the code.
However, on one of my forms within a project, this does not happen and I am unable to see the code.

Right clicking on the 'form.vb' in Solution Explorer and hitting 'view code' does not work either.
What have I done?

Comment: When you click the *Show all files* button in the Solution Explorer and expand some of your forms, does that one look the same as the others?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Yes it looks the same. I've decided to cut my losses, delete the form and start again. Waste of a days work, but hey...

Comment: One thing that has worked for me on occasion when a form goes haywire is the following. Add another WinForms project to the solution, drag the form from the existing project to the new one in the Solution Explorer to copy it, make any necessary changes to get the new project to compile, delete the original form, drag the form from the new project back to the existing project, then delete the new project. This causes VS to regenerate some file(s) associated with the form and can address some issues.

Comment: Thank you. I'll remember that for the future.